# Getting "Cannot GET /" on the front page with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to Node.js. After watching many explanatory videos and reading the Node.js docs, I started developing the site while respecting an MVC structure. The node server seems to work, but the display on the front shows `Cannot GET /`. Here is the [Browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA1SG.jpg) and the [MVC structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZzyT.jpg)

index.js code :

```
'use strict';
/* eslint-env node, es6 */

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4242;

app.use('/', require('./routes/home_route'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`serveur démaré: localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

home_controller.js code :

```
'use strict';

const homeView = (req, res) => {
    res.render("home_view", {
    } );
}
module.exports =  { homeView };
```

home_route.js code :

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const { homeView } = require('../controllers/home_controller');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/home', homeView);
module.exports = router;
```

And `home_view.ejs` is just html. I don't understand where my mistake is, the code seems correct to me. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have any route handler for `/`. You are only handling `/home`. What you are saying with this line `app.use('/', require('./routes/home_route'));` is that every time I receive a request on `/`, I passe it to that `router` inside `home_route.js`, which only handles `/home`.

One way to solve this is to redirect the request you get on `/` to `/home` which is already handled. For that change `home_route.js` to:

```
const express = require('express');
const { homeView } = require('../controllers/home_controller');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/home', homeView);
router.get('/', (req, res)=> res.redirect('/home')); // line I added
module.exports = router;
```